# How to get the values for the next and next next date in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

We have a table with columns Effective_Date, CVal,CPrice

How do we query the table to return values from these 2 rows in 1 row:

1. CVal (NextVal) and CPrice (NextPrice) values from row with Effective_Date the next date after somedate
2. CVal (SecondVal) and CPrice (SecondPrice) values from row with Effective_Date the next date after the Effective_Date from #1

For ex:

```
Effective_Date  CVal   CPrice
01-JAN-19       1       100
01-JAN-20       2       101
01-JAN-21       3       102
01-JAN-22       4       103
```

Say somedate = '31-DEC-19'

Expected result

(the next date after '31-DEC-19' in the Effective_Date column is 01-JAN-20,

and the next date after that is 01-JAN-21):

```
NextVal NextPrice SecondVal SecondPrice
2       101       3         102
```

Thank you.

Edited with answer from zip (replaced "top" with where rownum = 1, since top doesn't work on my Oracle) :

```
  select t.* from
 (
  lead(CVal, 1) over(order by Effective_Date) as NextVal 
  ,lead(CPrice, 1) over(order by Effective_Date) as NextPrice  
  ,lead(CVal, 2) over(order by Effective_Date) as SecondVal 
  ,lead(CPrice, 2) over(order by Effective_Date) as SecondPrice
  from tbl where Effective_Date >=  '31-DEC-19'
  order by Effective_Date ) t
  where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window functions for it

```
    select  
    lead(CVal, 1) over(order by Effective_Date) as NextVal 
    ,lead(CPrice, 1) over(order by Effective_Date) as NextPrice  
    ,lead(CVal, 2) over(order by Effective_Date) as SecondVal 
    ,lead(CPrice, 2) over(order by Effective_Date) as SecondPrice

    from tbl where Effective_Date >=  '31-DEC-19'
    where rownum = 1
    order by Effective_Date
```

Output is

```
NextVal NextPrice SecondVal SecondPrice
2       101       3         102
```

Comment: @faujong . . . It is surprising that you accepted this answer, given that the code does not work in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one row, you can filter and order the table and limit the values:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      where t.effective_date > date '2019-12-31'
      order by t.effective_date
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Then you can add `lead()` to pull in additional columns from the "next" row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(cval) over (order by effective_date) as next_cval,
             lead(price) over (order by effective_date) as next_price
      from t
      where t.effective_date > date '2019-12-31'
      order by t.effective_date
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: I edited my original post with the answer from zip. Thank you for your help